# Finding the inverse of trig functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse

I'm supposed to find the inverse of $$f(x) = \cos(x)+x$$

I usually just substitute $x$ for $y$ and then re-arrange. What do I do in this scenario?

Comment: Is this part of a bigger problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are being asked to **find** the inverse?  There is probably no simple answer to that.  If you only need to **prove the inverse exists** it's not so hard.

Comment: Why would you need to find the inverse to calculate that?

Comment: Sorry, I see I did a typo

Comment: I'm to find $$f^{-1} (1)$$

Comment: @Paze You're looking for $x$ such that $f(x)=1$. It's easy to guess.

Comment: Guess I just don't think of inverses like that...They sometimes boggle me...Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find $f^{-1}(1)$, which I will have set equal to $a$.

$$f^{-1}(1)=a$$

$$\implies1=f(a)$$

$$1=\cos(x)+x$$

By observation, $x=0$ is a solution.

By graphing, it is the only solution.